# Tree from array of objects with dot seperated property

Tags: javascript, tree, antd

Hello I have an array of objects like this:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnvF6.png)

groups are separated to maximum of 3 levels like: Baseline.name.name.

and i would like to create a tree structure of nested objects. Like this:

```
[
 {
    title: "Baseline",
    key: "root",
    children: [**...NESTED CHILDREN HERE WITH THE SAME STRUCTURE AS ROOT**],
 },
];
```

I need this for a ant design tree component: [https://ant.design/components/tree](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

How do I do this please???

I tried multiple approaches most of them from answers on stack overflow but i didnt manage to get the exact structure i want.

Comment: But without your prior code, it is from scratch? It's far better to help you with code you have already used.

Comment: @JozefMüller can you provide an elaborate example. I can't visualize what kind of structure you want

Comment: Please don't provide images of console output to describe your input. Type the text -- not in console output format, but valid JavaScript format. *"i didnt manage to get the exact structure i want."*: please add your best attempt and what you have found while debugging the problem that arose.